# Interpretation of the symmetry group given for the rotations' symmetries of the cube.

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

In the 10th edition of Gallian, is the proof of theorem 7.5, to show that the symmetry group of the cube is isomorphic to $S_4,$ when the $4$ long diagonals are used to represent the $24$ symmetries.

[image]

It states that there the rotations contain an $8$ element subgroup $$\{e, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3,
\beta^2, \beta^2\alpha, \beta^2\alpha^2, \beta^2\alpha^3\}$$
It states the cube's long diagonals' based symmetries about the midpoints of the anti-podal faces, parallel to the $x-z$ direction as:$\alpha=(1234),$ while states:
'*another $90^o$ rotation about an axis perpendicular to the first axis, to yield the permutation :$\beta= (1423).$*'

$\beta$ is $90^o$ clockwise (ck) rotation about the anti-podal faces, parallel to the $x-y$ axis.

Hence, $\beta^2= 180^o= (12)(34)$ cck rotation; and $\beta^3= 270^o= (1324)$ cck rotation.

$\alpha=90^o$ cck rotation in one plane, while $\beta^3=90^o$ ck rotation in a perpendicular plane ($x-y$). Or, $\beta$ is $270^o$ cck rotation in the same perpendicular plane ($x-y$).

*The orientation of the symmetry $\beta$ does not make difference to the subgroup of $8$ symmetries, even if it were $90^o$ cck rotation, as $\beta^2$ is still the same.

Say, if $\beta= (1324)=90^o$ cck rotation, still $\beta^2= 180^o$ rotation, in either cck or ck direction.*

Next, state the $4$ long diagonals' based permutations:

$\alpha=(1234),$
$\alpha^2=(13)(24),$
$\alpha^3=(1432),$
$\beta^3 = (1324),$
$\beta^2= (12)(34),$

Next, get the remaining symmetries of the subgroup as:

$\beta^2\alpha = (12)(34)(1234)= (24),$
$\beta^2\alpha^2 = (12)(34)(13)(24)= (14)(23),$
$\beta^2\alpha^3 = (12)(34)(1234)(13)(24)= (13).$

This leads to the subgroup being given as:

$\{e, \alpha=(1234), \alpha^2=
(13)(24), \alpha^3=
(1432), \beta^2=
(12)(34),  \beta^2\alpha=
(24), \beta^2\alpha^2=
 (14)(23), \beta^2\alpha^3=(13)\},$
or:
$$\{e, (1234), (13)(24), (1432), (12)(34), (24), (14)(23), (13)\}$$

Next, states the order of element $\alpha\beta= (1234)(1423)= (142),$ an order $3$ element.

---

In the given subgroup, the types of rotations, given by the permutations is of two different types:

1. $(24), (13),$ give rotations about anti-podal edges,
2. Rest are rotations, but of different amount of rotations, and along different axis formed by all three different anti-podal faces.
   a) $(1234)$ is a $90^o$ counter-clockwise rotation symmetry, along the axis formed by the midpoints of anti-podal faces along the $x-z$ axis; while $(1432)$ is $270^o$ rotation, along the same axis.
   b) rest are $180^o$ rotations along each of the three anti-podal faces.

---

Doubt #1: The significance of taking an $8$ element subgroup, and an order $3$ element is unclear.

It makes sense only if, have $3$ elements of the cube of a certain type, and each can have $8$ symmetries.

There are six faces, and $3$ pairs of anti-podal faces.
An axis through such a pair of anti-podal faces has $4$ rotation symmetries in the $0^o, 90^o, 180^o, 270^o$ cck direction; rather than $8.$
Also, an order $3$ element is taken as the permutation corresponding to $\pm120^o$ rotation about a pair of anti-podal vertices.
So, request why the above subgroup, and an order $3$ element is taken?

Doubt #2: The proof states : "*But, we must be careful not to assume that different rotations correspond to different permutations.*"

But, seems not elaborates it.
There are $24=4!$ permutations/symmetries, but it is "not" possible to have same rotations by different symmetries.

Say, to get a $180^o$ rotation about the anti-podal edges, can "not" get it by two different permutations.

Taking the cube labelled as per the vertices, as below. Let, the initial configuration is denoted by: $[1234][5678].$

An alternative (and, easier) example is that the symmetry $(12)(34)$ brings the final configuration $[3412][7856].$

I don't see if any two symmetries can bring the same configuration, of the initial cube.

[image]

---

***Edit:*** For the $8$ element group, let $G,$ there are four group properties:
1.Closure wrt the group operation, here composition (let, be denoted by $\star$) of the group symmetries. Formally stated, $\forall a,b\in G,$ then $a\star b\in G.$
2. Associativity wrt the group operation. $\forall x,y,z\in G, x\star (y \star z)= (x\star y)\star z.$
3. Identity element, $e,$ exists in the group. $\exists e\in G,\, \text{s.t.}\, \forall x\in G, e\star x= x\star e = x.$
4. Inverse exists for all elements in the group. $\forall x \in G, \exists y\in G, \, \text{s.t.}\, x\star y = y\star x = e.$

The easiest to prove is the property of having the identity element. It would need only $n$ operation, in the worst case, for an $n$ element group. Though, here it is obvious that $\epsilon= e.$

Next need find inverse.

The members are:
$$\{e=\epsilon, \alpha=(1234), \alpha^2=
(13)(24), \alpha^3=
(1432), \beta^2=
(12)(34),  \beta^2\alpha=
(24), \beta^2\alpha^2=
 (14)(23), \beta^2\alpha^3=(13)\}.$$

$(1234)$ is of order $4,$ so cannot be its own inverse.
Get $(1234)(1432)= e,$ or $\alpha\star \alpha^3= e.$

$\alpha^2$ is its own inverse.
Also, $\beta^2$ is its own inverse, as an order $2$ symmetry.

Rest of the non-trivial elements are their own inverse, as all are order $2$ symmetries.

Next need show closure.

Seems it is better to simply construct the Cayley table, as all four properties are shown by that alone.

*Request if there is a shortcut to the same.*

The group table is:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
e&e=\epsilon&\alpha=(1234)& \alpha^2=
(13)(24)& \alpha^3=
(1432)& \beta^2=
(12)(34)&  \beta^2\alpha=
(24)& \beta^2\alpha^2=
 (14)(23)& \beta^2\alpha^3=(13)\\ \hline
\alpha
&\alpha&\alpha^2& \alpha^3&e&
\alpha\beta^2=(1234)
(12)(34)=(13)=\beta^2\alpha^3& \alpha\beta^2\alpha=
(1234)(24)=(12)(34)=\beta^2& \alpha\beta^2\alpha^2=(1234)
 (14)(23)=(24)=\beta^2\alpha& \alpha\beta^2\alpha^3 =(1234)(13)=(14)(23)=\beta^2\alpha^2\\ \hline
\alpha^2&\alpha^2=(13)(24)& \alpha^3=(1432)=\alpha^3&e&\alpha&\alpha^2\beta^2=(13)(24)
(12)(34)=(14)(23)=\beta^2\alpha^2 &\alpha^2\beta^2\alpha=
(13)(24)(24)=(13)=\beta^2\alpha^3& \alpha^2\beta^2\alpha^2=(13)(24)
 (14)(23)=(12)(34)=\beta^2&\alpha^2\beta^2\alpha^3 =(13)(24)(13)=(24)=\beta^2\alpha\\ \hline
\alpha^3&\alpha^3=(1432)=\alpha^3& e&\alpha=(1234)&\alpha^2=(13)(24)&\alpha^3\beta^2=(1432)
(12)(34)=(24)=\beta^2\alpha &\alpha^3\beta^2\alpha=
(1432)(24)=(23)(14)=\beta^2\alpha^2& \alpha^3\beta^2\alpha^2=(1432)
 (14)(23)=(13)=\beta^2\alpha^3 &\alpha^3\beta^2\alpha^3 =(1432)(13)=(12)(34)=\beta^2\\ \hline
\beta^2&\beta^2=
(12)(34)&\beta^2\alpha=
(12)(34)(1234)=(24)=\beta^2\alpha&\beta^2\alpha^2=(12)(34)(13)(24)=(14)(23)&\beta^2\alpha^3=(14)(23)(1234)=(13)&e &\alpha=
(1234)& \alpha^2=(13)(24) &\alpha^3 =(1432) \\ \hline
\beta^2\alpha&\beta^2\alpha=
(24)&\beta^2\alpha\alpha=
(24)(1234)=(14)(23)=\beta^2\alpha^2& \beta^2\alpha\alpha^2=(24)(13)(24)=(13)=\beta^2\alpha^3
& \beta^2\alpha\alpha^3=(24)(1432)= (12)(43)=\beta^2& \beta^2\alpha\beta^2
=(24)(12)(34)=(1432)=\alpha^3 &\beta^2\alpha\beta^2\alpha=e&\beta^2\alpha\beta^2\alpha^2=(24)(14)(23)=(2341)=\alpha &\beta^2\alpha\beta^2\alpha^3 =(24)(13)=\alpha^2 \\ \hline
\beta^2\alpha^2&\beta^2\alpha^2=(14)(23)=\beta^2\alpha^2&\beta^2\alpha^2\alpha=(14)(23)(1234)=(13)=\beta^2\alpha^3 & \beta^2\alpha^2\alpha^2=(14)(23)(13)(24)= (12)(43)=\beta^2&\beta^2\alpha^2\alpha^3=(14)(23)(1432)=(24)=\beta^2\alpha&\beta^2\alpha^2\beta^2=(14)(23)(12)(34)=(13)(24) =\alpha^2&\beta^2\alpha^2\beta^2\alpha=(14)(23)(24)= (1432)=\alpha^3&\beta^2\alpha^2\beta^2\alpha^2= e &\beta^2\alpha^2\beta^2\alpha^3=(1234)=\alpha\\ \hline
\beta^2\alpha^3&\beta^2\alpha^3=(13)&\beta^2=(12)(34)&
\beta^2\alpha=(24)&\beta^2\alpha^2=(14)(23)&\beta^2\alpha^3\beta^2=(13)(12)(34)=(1234)=\alpha&\beta^2\alpha^3\alpha=(13)(24)=\alpha^2&\beta^2\alpha^3\beta^2\alpha^2=(13)(14)(23)=(1432)=\alpha^3 &\beta^2\alpha^3\beta^2\alpha^3 =e \\ \hline
\end{array}

But, still not helped as the two doubts still remain, particularly the first one.

Comment: The edit contains attempt to solve exercise $77,$ as stated in the proof. But, that is not core to the problem, and not helps even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text could be improved by using more precise language, but perhaps the author did want to burden the reader with pedantic verbiage.

Regarding doubt 2: Let $G$ be the group of rotations of the cube and let $S_4$ denote the permutation group of the diagonals
We can associate to each $g\in G$ a permutation $\phi(g)\in S_4$.
Let $\phi(G)=G'\subset S_4$ denote the associated subgroup of $S_4$.
One issue  raised in the sentence "we must be careful not to assume that different rotations correspond to different permutations" can be restated as the possibility that $\phi$ need not be 1-1.  That is, there might be a nontrivial $g
\in G$ for which $\phi(g)=e$ is the identity permutation on diagonals. In other words there might be a rotation of the cube $g$ that maps each diagonal line to itself.   The other issue to worry about is that $\phi$ need not be onto. That is, perhaps there is a permutation of the diagonals that cannot be accomplished using only rotations.

Regarding doubt 1:  If a group $G'$ has subgroups of orders $a$ and $b$  then a general theorem asserts that $a$ and $b$ must be divisors of the order of $G'$.  Since in our case $a=3$ and $b=8$   are relatively prime, $24$ divides the order of $G'$. Thus $G'$ has order 24 or 48 or 72 or . But $G'\subset S_4$ so 24 is the only possibility. This is the roundabout method by which the author shows that all 24 permutations of the diagonals can be accomplished by rotations. Thus $\phi$ is onto. Since the cardinality of the domain and range of $\phi$ are both 24, that ensures that $\phi$ is also 1-1. Thus both issues suggested in the quoted passage are resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the fact that $\alpha, \beta,$ are symmetries on perpendicular axis, hence disjoint; also of importance here? Or, is it that $(8,3)=1,$ i.e. are relatively prime, enough to convey this information?

Comment: Also even if the relatively prime orders of the $8$ element subgroup, and the order $3$ element, conveys the information of being mutually disjoint, how the subgroup is formed is unclear.

Comment: Stated another way, what properties are used to design the subgroup, and the choice of the element.

Comment: Also, can I design any alternative subgroup, and an element; such that their product yields the $24$ symmetries. If yes, how to find the total number of such ways.

Comment: The proof is purely based on number theory and only seeks to establish that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the two structures. Your interest in the detailed geometrical features of the rotation subgroups cannot be resolved using just number theory. However, the permutations in $S_4$ that fix exactly one element do I think correspond to rotations of the cube that fix that diagonal axis.